# Memory management for image data storing and retrieving with SwiftData (or CoreData)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swift-data

I know how to work with Data type in SwiftData (or CoreData). But the one question I feel missed is what is the correct way to care about memory management in different cases.

For example, I have the model for image Data:

```swift
@Model class ImageModel {
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) let data: Data
    
    var uiImage: UIImage { .init(data: data) ?? .init() }
    
    init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }
    
}
```

and the Item model:

```swift
@Model class Item {
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var images: [ImageModel] = []

    init() {}
    
}
```

The problem started when I tried to show items in the list because it's so ineffectively to use computed `var uiImage: UIImage { .init(data: data) ?? .init() }` for every image in every item I scroll. I considered several options, such as making a small proxy image data display in ItemView or lazy loading.

How do you achieve continuous smooth image loading and displaying in the list?

I considered several options, such as making a small proxy image data display in ItemView or lazy loading.

Comment: Lately I have been using a Transient instead of a computed. But I think a local url is best.

Comment: Good point! I think it's good to combine it with AsyncImage. I'll try it!